# Find position of first mismatch between two text/varchar columns

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns that should contain identical text - sometimes when the contents are large it is very difficult to find where the discrepancy is actually located.

It wouldn't be perfect but would be fairly helpful to have a function that would accept the two columns values and return the position where the first match occurs.  Since this would be called form within a select, performance would be fairly important, but it would only be run sporadically so not a huge concern.

Alternatively, a function that could do something similar to a DIFF in source control utilities would be ideal, but I can't imagine how complicated that would be.

Answer (score 1):

You can improve this solution a lot, but part from this logic:

```
declare @i as int
While @i < LEN(String1)
BEGIN
  SELECT @i AS "index"
  FROM YourTable
  WHERE SUBSTRING(String1, @i, 1) != SUBSTRING(String2, @i, 1)
  set @i = @i + 1
END
```

Comment: That's actually not bad.

Answer (score 0):

For finding whether two columns differ, you can use BINARY_CHECKSUM().  That is sensitive enough to pick up even a difference of upper case vs lower case.

As for finding the difference between two strings, I would go with 2 cte's and then use an EXCEPT.  The first result will be the first deviation from the string.

```
declare @test1 VARCHAR(1000) = 'I have two columns that should contain identical text - sometimes when the contents are large it is very difficult to find where the discrepancy is actually located.'
declare @test2 VARCHAR(1000) = 'I have two columns that should contain identical text - sometimes when the contents are Large it is very difficult to find where the discrepancy is actually located.'

SELECT CASE WHEN BINARY_CHECKSUM(@test1) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(@test2) THEN 'Identical' ELSE 'Not Identical' END AS check_


;with cte1 AS (
SELECT 
1 AS col_

UNION ALL 

SELECT col_ + 1
FROM cte1 
WHERE col_ < (SELECT LEN(@test1))
), 
 cte2 AS (
SELECT 
1 AS col_

UNION ALL 

SELECT col_ + 1
FROM cte2 
WHERE col_ < (SELECT LEN(@test2))
), final_cte AS (

SELECT col_, SUBSTRING(@test1, col_, 1) AS char_, BINARY_CHECKSUM(SUBSTRING(@test1, col_, 1)) AS char_checksum
FROM CTE1 

EXCEPT 

SELECT col_, SUBSTRING(@test2, col_, 1) AS char_, BINARY_CHECKSUM(SUBSTRING(@test2, col_, 1)) AS char_checksum
FROM CTE2
)

select col_, char_
FROM final_cte 
ORDER by col_ 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)
```

Comment: One shortfall I can see this having is if string1 is shorter than string 2.  This query would pick up differences all the way to the end of string1 and lose anything after that.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fcn_DiffPosition
(
    @str1 nvarchar(max),
    @str2 nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MinPosition int = NULL

    ;WITH cte1 AS
    (
        SELECT      1                       AS CharacterPosition,
                    SUBSTRING(@str1, 1, 1)  AS [Character]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      CharacterPosition + 1,
                    SUBSTRING(@str1, CharacterPosition + 1, 1)
        FROM        cte1
        WHERE       CharacterPosition < LEN(@str1)
    ),
    cte2 AS
    (
        SELECT      1                       AS CharacterPosition,
                    SUBSTRING(@str2, 1, 1)  AS [Character]
        UNION ALL
        SELECT      CharacterPosition + 1,
                    SUBSTRING(@str2, CharacterPosition + 1, 1)
        FROM        cte2
        WHERE       CharacterPosition < LEN(@str2)
    )

    SELECT      @MinPosition = MIN(ISNULL(cte1.CharacterPosition, cte2.CharacterPosition))
    FROM        cte1
    FULL JOIN   cte2 ON cte1.CharacterPosition = cte2.CharacterPosition
    WHERE       ISNULL(cte1.[Character], '') != ISNULL(cte2.[Character], '')
    OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 0)

    RETURN @MinPosition
END
```

The function will return null if the two strings are the same. Depending on your collation, this may be case-sensitive or not. Example:

```
SELECT dbo.fcn_DiffPosition('Hello World', 'HelloWorld') -- 6
SELECT dbo.fcn_DiffPosition('Hello',       'HelloWorld') -- 6
SELECT dbo.fcn_DiffPosition('Dog', 'Dog')                -- NULL
```